# Exception when open Android N shortcuts

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Android N shortcuts but it crashes with an exception 
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Shortcut could not be started`. I believe its because I am not giving the correct `targetPackageName` in `shortcuts.xml`

I am not really sure what it should be pointing to if the application itself is in a different module and the activity I am trying to start is in a different module.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. For me, the issue was that the Activity I was trying to launch only had an intent-filter for the LAUNCHER category. Once I created a separate intent filter that had category DEFAULT (ie, category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"), everything worked fine.

Note that if you're trying to use activities from different modules, it may be more flexible to use implicit intents. While your original approach will still work just fine, you may want to consider moving to using action constants instead of referring to the package name.

If that doesn't fix your problem, can you post your manifest and your shortcuts.xml?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in replying. The source of the problem was the way  project was setup to accommodate for international builds. I had to specify certain package for it to work. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: In case of dynamic shortcuts, changing the category to DEFAULT in my manifest solved my issue; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure `TargetPackageName` is Correct. Use package name where activity exist.

Use `ActivityName` like this:

`android:targetClass="com.example.logs.ExampleActivity"`

Use `Package` like this:

`android:targetPackage="com.example.logs"`

I Hope this works!!!

Comment: I did try the package in which activity exists but that didn't work either. I think the way app is setup with different international build flavors, something is going wrong